# Spotify API, Is possible a web app to vote my next music?

Tags: spotify

Using a spotify API I would like to make an web app to allow others people to vote to the next music to play in my computer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague question, but you could make something along the lines of a poll, then let the answer become the next song...